# Why doesn't drools 5.4 documentation say anything about JBPM FORM BUILDER and integration with Guvnor

Tags: forms, jbpm, formbuilder, drools-guvnor, guvnor

i have searched a lot about jbpm-form-builder and except for the blog or some posts I couldn't find anything about it. And also some videos on `vimeo.com`.

```
http://blog.athico.com/2012/07/jbpm-form-builder-state-of-art.html
```

But I am surprised to see that there is not much about jbpm-form-builder in drools documentations. This makes me think that is JBPM form builder good enough to be used in production environments or not. As community is also not much into form builder queries is it properly in to market or is it currently under development ?

I have tried to deploy it with guvnor but have found out some issues like ioData search is displaying processes only from defaultPackage. I don't get any process/or human task to associate the form if I archive the defaultPackage and try to create a form definition in a differnet package with multiple processesand and human tasks in it.

This is a point of concern as when I define roles and permissions in guvnor at that time I want users to access only those processes which fall under their access area.

Secondly, I tried to deploy guvnor and form builders on different nodes of JBOSS and configured preference.properties and sprinComponents.xml for this purpose. I found that guvnor was still accessing form builder with path relative to its context and I was getting Http-404 error in my guvnor's IFrame. If I open form builder in a standalone mode with this deployment structure it was properly accessing guvnor and displaying processes and human tasks from guvnor's default package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBOSS has not properly released it for the market. Or they might not have released it for community but for enterprise customers.